# Eclipse SVN File name with Last Commit Author and Date

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have been using Eclipse Indigo with SVN plugin.
All project files .*java, *.xhtml..etc are shown with filename with Last Commit Author and Commit Date.

How I can simplifiy all filenames so that they are seen as only its name.

lets say: File is shown like:

```
applicationContext.xml 7 9/30/13 11:45 AM mmc18
```

I want it to be seen like:

```
applicationContext.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Label preferences page in Eclipse.

*Window -> preferences-> Team -> SVN ->  Label Decoration*

More details can be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_label_decors.php)

Comment: your link allow me find another etting screen Window -> preferences-> General->Appearance->Label Decorations uncheck SVN

Answer (score 0):

Window -> preferences-> General->Appearance->Label Decorations uncheck SVN